# Я полный новичок в C# Помогите понять почему не работает мой код

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введи год твоего рождения:");
            string bornFalse = Console.ReadLine();
            short born = Convert.ToInt16(bornFalse);
            short NowDate = 2020;
            short ready = NowDate - born;
            Console.WriteLine("Твой возраст:" + ready);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как именно он не работает?

Comment: Ошибка CS0266 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "int" в "short". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов).

Comment: `short ready = (short)(NowDate - born);`

Comment: Вообще int16 это и есть short, странно это

Comment: @CrazyElf, в ошибке речь просто про int, который int32, а не int16

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тип `int` (он же `System.Int32`) - наименьший знаковый тип, для которого определены арифметические операции. Таким образом, вычитая `short` из `short` они **неявно** преобразуются к `int`, вычитаются и возвращается результат тоже типа `int`. Обратное преобразование (из `int` в `short`) может вызывать потерю значащих разрядов, поэтому возможно только **явное** преобразование:

```
short ready = (short) (NowDate - born);
```

Но лучше просто используйте везде `int` (для увеличения скорости доступа к памяти используется выравнивание, поэтому "сэкономленные" байты все равно окажутся недоступны)